# How to query cloud datastore from another App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to know which is the best way to query cloud datastore from another App Engine application.
When I was using cloud SQL, I queried it using SQLAlchemy. 
Should I use google cloud Endpoint API or is there a better way?

Comment: as you have determined you'll have to go through the app that's already "in front" of it by creating an interface (e.g. rest) that can be used by external applications. The "best" way, well, that's debatable.

Comment: Thank you! To make things clear, can you list out the ways you know to access the cloud datastore from another App Engine application so that I can find the best way for my use case.

Comment: put a rest API in front of it and use that. And there are endpoints, but I've never used those.